# groovy_test reports could not find class

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, bazel, bazel-rules

I run into some problems when trying to use [rules_groovy](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy).

**Minimal steps to reproduce:**

```
git clone https://github.com/Vertexwahn/BazelDemos
cd BazelDemos
cd GroovyDemo
bazel test //...
```

In the case you have not installed Bazel you can installed it on a Ubuntu 20.04 machine this way:

```
echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://storage.googleapis.com/bazel-apt stable jdk1.8" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bazel.list
curl https://bazel.build/bazel-release.pub.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bazel
```

**The problem:**

When I run `bazel test //...` I get the following error:

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.001
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [HelloWorldTest]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldTest
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
    ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

**Details to setup:**

My setup looks like this:

*.bazelverion*

```
5.1.0
```

*WORKSPACE.bazel*

```
# rules_groovy
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_groovy",
    sha256 = "a0714e766ba6584432a85697849b2b4f8f56ac634777441d8854a122f07798d2",
    strip_prefix = "rules_groovy-e110fbce55bad3b2db067198f339e719244f91b7",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy/archive/e110fbce55bad3b2db067198f339e719244f91b7.tar.gz",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_groovy//groovy:repositories.bzl", "rules_groovy_dependencies")

rules_groovy_dependencies()
```

*src/test/groovy/BUILD.bazel*

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_groovy//groovy:groovy.bzl", "groovy_test")

groovy_test(
    name = "HelloWorldTest",
    srcs = ["HelloWorldTest.groovy"],
)
```

*src/test/groovy/HelloWorldTest.groovy*

```
package src.test.groovy

import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase

class HelloWorldTest extends GroovyTestCase {
    void testAssertions() {
        assertTrue(1 == 1)
    }
}
```

It reports that class `HelloWorldTest` can not be found.
Any hints what I am doing wrong here?
What do I need to change to get a working Groovy unit test working?

My expectation is that the unit test succeeds.

(BTW: I am using Ubuntu 20.04)

**EDIT:**

I also tried to make use of `groovy_junit_test` by modifing the `BUILD.bazel` file this way:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_groovy//groovy:groovy.bzl", "groovy_junit_test")

groovy_junit_test(
    name = "HelloWorldTest",
    tests = ["HelloWorldTest.groovy"],
)
```

`bazel test //...` gives me:

> exec ${PAGER:-/usr/bin/less} "$0" || exit 1 Executing tests from
> //src/test/groovy:HelloWorldTest
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- JUnit version 4.12 .E Time: 0 There was 1 failure: 1)
> initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class
> [HelloWorldTest]  at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
> at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
> at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)    at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldTest  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)    at
> java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)     at
> org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)  at
> org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
> ... 4 more
>
> FAILURES!!! Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1

Comment: `package src.test.groovy` is wrong, the classes in this dir have no package name

Comment: @injecteer If I uncomment it (`package src.test.groovy`) I still get an error

Comment: @Vertexwahn, have you tried [groovy_junit_test](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy#groovy_junit_test) instead of `groovy_test`? because it sounds like `groovy_test` is just a test runner when `groovy_junit_test` compiles sources before calling groovy_test... https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy/blob/master/groovy/groovy.bzl#L295

Comment: @daggett I tried to use `groovy_junit_test` but it does not work - I update my question with this test and the results

Comment: ok, seems you don't have JAVA_HOME env var: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy/blob/master/groovy/groovy.bzl#L228

Comment: @daggett Sorry did the test run on a different system - now I executed it on Ubuntu again and the JAVA_HOME problem is gone

Answer (score 1):

use [groovy_junit_test](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy#groovy_junit_test) instead of `groovy_test`

according to documentation and [source code](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_groovy/blob/master/groovy/groovy.bzl#L295)  `groovy_test` is just a test runner

when `groovy_junit_test` compiles sources and then calls `groovy_test`

Comment: Makes sense. As I pointed out in my answer I tried also `groovy_junit_test` (had first an issue with missing `JAVA_HOME`, but this issue was fixed and then a new issue popped up -> `Could not find class [HelloWorldTest]` - if you have any hints for me how to fix this I would be glad to donate the bounty to you